# retrieve ID with jq manipulation

Tags: jq

I would like to retrieve the Name, ID of the OutputTransportList and ID of the WebPoints via jq.
Till now I can retrieve the Name, ID and all WebPoints, but my intension is to retrive only the ID of the WebPoints.

`jq '.OutputTransportList[]| [.Name,.ID,.PackagingInfo.WebList,.WebPoints.ID]'`

How can I do it with jq?

thank you.

```
  {
"Name_id": "New",
"Active": true,
"OutputTransportList": [{
    "ID": "{724BCC39-D287-4047-88E3-5E300F37BB37}",
    "Name": "TEST HD",
    "OutputServiceList": [{
        "ID": "{12E6CE83-8DCD-469D-A6EA-D4A4AAC9A3F1}",
        "Name": "TEST HD",
        "Enable": true
    }],
    "MWProfileList": [],
    "PackagingInfo": {
        "PackagingProfileList": [],
        "WebList": [{
            "WebPoints": [{
                "ID": "{c9d63dec-3d11-6f98-bcab-25db01ced512}",
                "RedundancyMode": "ACTIVE_ACTIVE",
                "PrimaryPointTemplateReference": "{74128CCE-1E50-43F5-BAB5-7E6E63541CA7}",
                "ResourceName": ""
            }]
        }]
    },
    "TransportInfo": {
        "Protocol": "IP"
    }
}],
"PoolList": []
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question with actual code, not an image.

Comment: sorry, it contains multiple lines. Isn't helping you the way I appended the photo?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You should create a very small, but representative, subset of the actual code, make sure it's valid json and post that.

Comment: ok I appended the code.

Comment: That's better, but the snippet you posted is invalid json. Please re-edit with a valid json.

Comment: I re-editted it, so now it's valid. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this expression with your actual json and see if it works:

```
.OutputTransportList[].PackagingInfo.WebList[].WebPoints[].ID
```

with your sample json, it outputs:

```
"{c9d63dec-3d11-6f98-bcab-25db01ced512}"
```